# Rails 4 - Routing the root route to an index action - Rspec Tests Failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I've decided to get back to basics with Rails for a bit and I'm working through thoughtbot's upcase online course.

Here are the tests:

```
describe "routes" do
  it "routes '/' to the index action of the pages controller" do
    expect(get: "/").to route_to(controller: "pages", action: "index")
  end
end

describe "root request" do
  it "shows a welcome message" do
    get "/"
    expect(response.body).to include("Welcome to My Guestbook")
  end
end

describe PagesController do
  describe "#index" do
    it "renders the welcome page" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to render_template("welcome")
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the output from Rspec:

```
Failures:

  1) PagesController#index renders the welcome page
     Failure/Error: get :index
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"pages"}
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) routes routes '/' to the index action of the pages controller
     Failure/Error: expect(get: "/").to route_to(controller: "pages", action: "index")
       The recognized options <{"controller"=>"pages", "action"=>"welcome"}> did not match <{"controller"=>"pages", "action"=>"index"}>, difference:.
       --- expected
       +++ actual
       @@ -1 +1 @@
       -{"controller"=>"pages", "action"=>"index"}
       +{"controller"=>"pages", "action"=>"welcome"}
     # ./spec/routing/routes_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#welcome'
end
```

My controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    render 'pages/welcome'
  end

end
```

I haven't worked with Rspec much, but as far as I can tell the application is doing exactly what the tests want it to.  Any help would be appreciated as I'm some what baffled right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have,

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#welcome'
end
```

and you should have:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#index'
end
```

Comment: Thank you, not sure how I missed that.

Comment: You are welcome. We all make that kind of mistakes ;)